# Moveable Mahapps SimpleChildWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I'm using [Mahapps.Metro.SimpleChildWindow](https://github.com/punker76/MahApps.Metro.SimpleChildWindow) to show a data input window. I would like for the entry window to be moveable. I've set "AllowMove" in my XAML markup, but the window still isn't moveable. Here is the XAML I'm using:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Project.Views.View"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"             
             xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
             xmlns:Dialog="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
             xmlns:iconPacks="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/iconpacks"
             xmlns:simpleChildWindow="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.SimpleChildWindow;assembly=MahApps.Metro.SimpleChildWindow"             
             Dialog:DialogParticipation.Register="{Binding}"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid">
        <simpleChildWindow:ChildWindow CloseByEscape="True"
                                       ChildWindowWidth="500"
                                       ChildWindowHeight="200"
                                       HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                       VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       Margin="10"
                                       ChildWindowImage="None"
                                       BorderBrush="{DynamicResource AccentBaseColorBrush}"
                                       GlowBrush="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}"
                                       IsModal="True"
                                       AllowMove="True"
                                       IsOpen="{Binding IsChildWindowOpen}"
                                       Title="View/Edit ">
            <Grid>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="15" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <!-- Child Window Content -->
            </Grid>
        </simpleChildWindow:ChildWindow>
        <-- Other controls and stuff -->
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I'm opening and closing the child window from the ViewModel by setting IsChildWindowOpen to true or false.

I have been looking at the [examples on GitHub](https://github.com/punker76/MahApps.Metro.SimpleChildWindow/tree/dev/src/MahApps.Metro.SimpleChildWindow.Demo) but the example with the moveable window is using XAML that is in an external file. I was using XAML nested in the current view so that I could bind to the current ViewModel instance.

What do I need to change to make the window moveable?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out. I needed to remove

```
HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
HorizontalAlignment="Center"
VerticalAlignment="Center"
```

from the window declaration.

```
    <simpleChildWindow:ChildWindow CloseByEscape="True"
                                       ChildWindowWidth="500"
                                       ChildWindowHeight="180"
                                       Margin="10"
                                       BorderThickness="1"
                                       ChildWindowImage="None"
                                       BorderBrush="{DynamicResource AccentBaseColorBrush}"
                                       CloseOnOverlay="True"
                                       GlowBrush="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}"
                                       AllowMove="True"
                                       IsOpen="{Binding IsChildWindowOpen}"
</simpleChildWindow:ChildWindow>
```